# Python - Read an image from URL to resize and convert image to grayscale

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-image

I want to read an image from URL to resize and convert it to grayscale. I have seen a number of examples from stackoverflow and I tried them out. However, it never successfully converts image to grayscale in my case. I'm not sure what went wrong here. This are what I tried.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np 
from skimage import io, color

# try 1
img1 = io.imread("https://prasadpamidi.github.io/images/image2.jpg", as_grey=True)
img1 = (img1 - 255.0) / 255
img1 = resize(img1, (32, 32))


# try 2
img1 = io.imread("https://prasadpamidi.github.io/images/image2.jpg")
img1 = img1.dot([0.07, 0.72, 0.21])
img1 = (img1 - 255.0) / 255
img1 = resize(img1, (32, 32))

# try 3
img1 = color.rgb2gray(io.imread("https://prasadpamidi.github.io/images/image2.jpg"))
img1 = (img1 - 255.0) / 255
img1 = resize(img1, (32, 32))

# print images
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.show()
```

The result more or less is similar to below. So, I'd like to know what I missed. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The image is colorcoded by `imshow`. To display a greyscale image it should either be a RGB image with all 3 idential channels, or if it is a single channel image, you would need to use a grey colormap, `plt.imshow("path.png", cmap="Greys")`.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest of course, if I parametise `cmap="Greys"`  then, it will plot in grayscale but I guess what I really want to know is if any of those three techniques yields the array that correctly transforms the image to grayscale.

Comment: Not sure what "correctly" means. All three options will produce a grey scale image.   You'd usually normalize with 255 instead of 256 to cover the full range of an 8bit image. And you need to decide for yourself if accounting for the perceptual difference between channels (`.dot([0.07, 0.72, 0.21])`) is needed or not.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest what I meant was after the transformation, my array become grayscale or not really. Oh! and I updated to 255. thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this code a try:

```
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

url = "https://prasadpamidi.github.io/images/image2.jpg"
img1 = imread(url, as_gray=True)
img2 = resize(img1, (32, 32))
img3 = img_as_ubyte(img2)
imshow(img3)
```

Output:

[image: grayscale image]

I'm attaching a screenshot of the variable explorer to show you that the variables have the correct shape and type.

[image: screenshot of variable explorer]

Comment: @ Tonechas thank you for your answer. I have tried it. when I run this code for the first time, it doesn't produce any plot. However, If run it for the second time, it produce a plot that has blue background in the sign with white arrow which is very strange.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.3, scikit-image 0.14.0 and Spyder 3.3.1. Are you using the same Python/skimage versions and IDE?

Comment: @ Tonechas My Python version is 3.6.3, scikit-image 0.13.0  and Spyder 3.2.4. My img1 is [[[209, 214, 220] of `uint8`. img2 is [[[0.74633981, 0.75240598, 0.78928366], and img3 is [[[190, 192, 201] of `uint8` datatype.

Comment: I'd suggest you to install the latest versions through `conda update spyder` and `conda update scikit-image`. Then restart Spyder and run the snippet in my answer again. This should work.

Comment: This is unrelated to spyder. No need to update that one. It can only depend on numpy, scikit-image, and matplotlib. Getting the newest versions of those is sure helpful.

Comment: @ Tonechas After I updated those, it plotted the grayscale image. However, it's still needed to be run twice. And also, this approach worked on my local machine. I wouldn't be able to update those on the production one :/

Comment: To wrap up: `resize(imread(url, as_gray=True), (32, 32))` should do the trick. You don't need to perform the conversion to grayscale manually. To display the converted image in grayscale use `cmap="Greys"` as pointed out by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: @ Tonechas Thank you  :)